# pass parameter from controller to models condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to bind a param to a join via a named scope., but I'm getting an error.

What is the correct way to do that?

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base

    #relations
    has_many :votes, :inverse_of => :idea
    has_one :has_voted, :class_name => 'Vote', :conditions => ['ip = :ip']

    # named scopes
    scope :with_vote, lambda {|ip| {
        :include => [:has_voted],
        # like this ??
        :conditions => [:has_voted => {:conditions => {:userIp => ip}} ] 
    }}

end
```

`Idea.with_vote(request.ip).all`

I believe I need the condition definition in the model for it to appear in the **ON** clause of a **JOIN**, rather then in the **WHERE** one.

---

**Edit** I'm trying to get the following query

```
select Ideas.*, Votes.* from Ideas 
left outer join Votes 
on Votes.Idea_id = Idea.id AND Votes.ip = {request.ip}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can use incomplete conditions in an association. 
If I understand correctly, you need Idea has many votes and votes records the request.ip and idea id.
You want the scope to retrieve all ideas your current request ip voted for.

```
class Idea
  has_many :votes

  scope :with_vote_from_ip, lambda {|ip| {
    :include => [:votes],
    :conditions => ['votes.ip = ?', ip] 
  }}
end
```

but if you want all ideas including only votes from current up you need extra conditions on the outer join. I think this is not possible without sql fragment:

```
class Idea
  has_many :votes

  scope :with_vote_from_ip, lambda {|ip| {
    :joins => 'left outer join Votes on Votes.Idea_id = Idea.id AND Votes.ip = #{ip}' 
  }}
end
```

now `Idea.with_vote_from_ip(request.ip).all` should work.

Comment: I want **all** ideas and a flag indicating whether the current user has voted for it or not.

Comment: In this case i'm getting the following query:
`SELECT ... FROM "ideas" LEFT OUTER JOIN "ideas_votes" ON "ideas_votes"."idea_id" = "ideas"."id" WHERE (votes.ip = '127.0.0.1')`

and the ip appears on the where, not on the **ON** clause

Comment: That's exactly the way I've implemented it, although couldn't do it the ActiveRecord way. Thank you ;)